# Mapping to a Variable and retrieving once they match

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mapping, flash-builder

I have a list of check boxes that when selected the getEventName method should reurn the key that matches the label. For example if the label is "NEW", the key should be returned when map[key] = "new". These have been defined in the LABEL_EVENTTYPE function below. It is always returning an empty string and can't seem to figure out why.

```
public static const LABEL_EVENTTYPE_MAP:Object = {
        "CANCEL":["cancelled","expired", "doneForDay"],
        "NEW":["new"],
        "TRADE":["trade"],
        "AMEND":["replaced"],

}





private function getEventName(label:String):String{
            var map:Object = ReplayConstants.LABEL_EVENTTYPE_MAP;
            for each(var key:String in map){

                if (map[key] == label){
                    return key;
                }       

        }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through object properties requires `for..in` loop instead of `for each.. in`

```
for (var key:String in map){
    if (map[key] == label){
       return key;
    }       
}
```

Also take into account, that objects in your map are arrays, that's why your comparison `map[key] == label` will always return `false`.